# Removing "HTTP://" From the_author_meta?

Tags: author, user-meta

By default WordPress prints http:// in front of URLS users add in their profile, which are called using the following code:

```
<?php the_author_meta('user_url'); ?>
```

Could somebody provide me the code to strip these URLS of "HTTP://" by default?  (While still working as a link and not touching WP's backend... I assume this could be a function?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the author's id is `$author_id`, the following code should work. You can of course use this to create your own function.

```
<?php $url = get_the_author_meta('user_url', $author_id); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo str_replace('http://', '', $url);?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_the_user_url_printable( $author_id = false ) {

    if ( $author_id ) {
        $user_url = get_the_author_meta( 'user_url', $author_id );
    } else {
        $user_url = get_the_author_meta( 'user_url' );
    }

    if ( !$user_url ) {
        $user_url = get_author_posts_url( $author_id );
    }

    return preg_replace( '/^(\w+:)\/*(.*)\/$/', '$2', $user_url );
}
?>
```

The aforementioned code block...

1. meets the WordPress Codex [Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards), as confirmed by mrchrisadams' [WordPress Coding Standards](https://github.com/mrchrisadams/WordPress-Coding-Standards) CodeSniffer ruleset;
2. guesses the `$author_id` if inside a Loop;
3. falls back on the url delivered by `get_author_posts_url()` if the author has not explicitly entered a URL;
4. is agnostic about the protocol (stripping `http://`, `https://`, `git://`, or even `mailto:`);
5. and is a function, as per the request.